# Secure authentication JS Client and Azure App

Tags: javascript, azure

I have a JS client side application that sends a POST request to an Azure Endpoint, using hardcoded SPA client_id and most importantly client_secret as displayed below:

```
 function(request, sender, sendResponse) {
  let data = new FormData();
  data.append('client_id', "xxx");
  data.append("client_secret", "xxxx");
  data.append("grant_type", "password");
  data.append("scope", "https://management.azure.com/user_impersonation");
  data.append("username", request.usr);
  data.append("password", request.pass);

  const myHeaders = new Headers({
      Accept:"application/json"
  });
  let resp = fetch(url, { 
    headers : myHeaders,
    method: "POST",
    body: data,
    mode: 'cors'
  }).then( (response) => {
        // do some stuff
    })
}
```

I need to protect these secrets as they should never be accessed by the client directly, so i have created a backend node server in Azure, that listens for the JS client.

But i'm confronted to the same problem again :

How to authenticate the JS client app so that only it, can post requests to the node Azure service, without storing a secret / certificate in the client side ?

As of now the node service is only accessible through authenticated accounts, but if i have to load a token in the JS client again, i go back to the original problem ...

Is there a different way to look at this problem ? Or an other techique to achieve this sort of flow ?

Comment: You cant authenticate the js app, but you can authenticate the users of the js app with their credentials and issue them a cookie

Comment: I need the app to authenticate in the background, so no interaction allowed in my case unfortunately

Comment: The js will need to have a token, which can be stolen, i don't think there is a way to ensure that the client interacting with your server is a genuine client, i could interact with your server using python and you will never know

Comment: You could look at this question for more info : https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/246434/how-can-i-ensure-my-api-is-only-called-by-my-client

Answer (score 1):

The standard way to retrieve access tokens to call backend services from a client side app is to use an authorization code flow. Usually you'll use a library for this, such as [MSAL](https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-js).

Using authorization code flow, the user will go through the Oauth login process, and you'll write code to request an access token on the user's behalf using their security context.

The user will have to have access to the resources in question, and in AAD  you'll have to enable the API permissions for management.azure.com.